# Bitnami Trac 0.11.6 SVN Post commit hooks failing

Tags: python, svn, apache, trac, bitnami

Beating my head against a wall here for a day trying to get post commit hooks work so I can add refs/ close tickets in trac from an SVN commit.
I used the bitnami trac stack to install and am fairly happy with the way its setup.

Every commit though gives the error

> svn: MERGE of "/svn/Project": 200 OK (http://10.0.0.204)

I can see from various posts that this is down to the post commit hook failing but thesvn commit succeding. I've used the standard script from the edgewall site and my files look like the below  (sorry for the length these make the post but I guess the more info the better..)

*post-commit.cmd*

```
@ECHO OFF 


:: POST-COMMIT HOOK 
:: 
:: The post-commit hook is invoked after a commit.  Subversion runs 
:: this hook by invoking a program (script, executable, binary, etc.) 
:: named 'post-commit' (for which this file is a template) with the  
:: following ordered arguments: 
:: 
::   [1] REPOS-PATH   (the path to this repository) 
::   [2] REV          (the number of the revision just committed) 
:: 
:: The default working directory for the invocation is undefined, so 
:: the program should set one explicitly if it cares. 
:: 
:: Because the commit has already completed and cannot be undone, 
:: the exit code of the hook program is ignored.  The hook program 
:: can use the 'svnlook' utility to help it examine the 
:: newly-committed tree. 
:: 
:: On a Unix system, the normal procedure is to have 'post-commit' 
:: invoke other programs to do the real work, though it may do the 
:: work itself too. 
:: 
:: Note that 'post-commit' must be executable by the user(s) who will 
:: invoke it (typically the user httpd runs as), and that user must 
:: have filesystem-level permission to access the repository. 
:: 
:: On a Windows system, you should name the hook program 
:: 'post-commit.bat' or 'post-commit.exe', 
:: but the basic idea is the same. 
::  
:: The hook program typically does not inherit the environment of 
:: its parent process.  For example, a common problem is for the 
:: PATH environment variable to not be set to its usual value, so 
:: that subprograms fail to launch unless invoked via absolute path. 
:: If you're having unexpected problems with a hook program, the 
:: culprit may be unusual (or missing) environment variables. 
::  
:: Here is an example hook script, for a Unix /bin/sh interpreter. 
:: For more examples and pre-written hooks, see those in 
:: the Subversion repository at 
:: http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/ and 
:: http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/ 


setlocal 


:: Debugging setup 
:: 1. Make a copy of this file. 
:: 2. Enable the command below to call the copied file. 
:: 3. Remove all other commands 
::call %~dp0post-commit-run.cmd %* > %1/hooks/post-commit.log 2>&1 


:: Call Trac post-commit hook 
call %~dp0trac-post-commit-hook.cmd %* || exit 1
```

*trac-post-commit-hook.cmd*

```
@ECHO OFF 
:: 
:: Trac post-commit-hook script for Windows 
:: 
:: Contributed by markus, modified by cboos. 


:: Usage: 
:: 
:: 1) Insert the following line in your post-commit.bat script 
:: 
:: call %~dp0\trac-post-commit-hook.cmd %1 %2 
:: 
:: 2) Check the 'Modify paths' section below, be sure to set at least TRAC_ENV 


setlocal 


:: ---------------------------------------------------------- 
:: Modify paths here: 


:: -- this one *must* be set 
SET TRAC_ENV=E:\Trac\Project\Project


:: -- set if Python is not in the system path 
:: SET PYTHON_PATH= 


:: -- set to the folder containing trac/ if installed in a non-standard location 
:: SET TRAC_PATH= "C:\Program Files\Bitnami Trac Stack\"
:: ---------------------------------------------------------- 


:: Do not execute hook if trac environment does not exist 
IF NOT EXIST %TRAC_ENV% GOTO :EOF 


set PATH=%PYTHON_PATH%;%PATH% 
set PYTHONPATH=%TRAC_PATH%;%PYTHONPATH% 


SET REV=%2 


:: Resolve ticket references (fixes, closes, refs, etc.) 
Python "%~dp0trac-post-commit-resolve-ticket-ref.py" -p "%TRAC_ENV%" -r "%REV%" 


endlocal
```

haven't removed the comments from the trac path there but don't think it should be needed. Finally the script from edgewall..

*trac-post-commit-resolve-ticket-ref.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# trac-post-commit-hook
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2004 Stephen Hansen 
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to
# deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the
# rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or
# sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
#   The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
#   all copies or substantial portions of the Software. 
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
# THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
# FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS
# IN THE SOFTWARE.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# This Subversion post-commit hook script is meant to interface to the
# Trac (http://www.edgewall.com/products/trac/) issue tracking/wiki/etc 
# system.
# 
# It should be called from the 'post-commit' script in Subversion, such as
# via:
#
# REPOS="$1"
# REV="$2"
# TRAC_ENV="/path/to/tracenv"
#
# /usr/bin/python /usr/local/src/trac/contrib/trac-post-commit-hook \
#  -p "$TRAC_ENV" -r "$REV"
#
# (all the other arguments are now deprecated and not needed anymore)
#
# It searches commit messages for text in the form of:
#   command #1
#   command #1, #2
#   command #1 & #2 
#   command #1 and #2
#
# Instead of the short-hand syntax "#1", "ticket:1" can be used as well, e.g.:
#   command ticket:1
#   command ticket:1, ticket:2
#   command ticket:1 & ticket:2 
#   command ticket:1 and ticket:2
#
# In addition, the ':' character can be omitted and issue or bug can be used
# instead of ticket.
#
# You can have more than one command in a message. The following commands
# are supported. There is more than one spelling for each command, to make
# this as user-friendly as possible.
#
#   close, closed, closes, fix, fixed, fixes
#     The specified issue numbers are closed with the contents of this
#     commit message being added to it. 
#   references, refs, addresses, re, see 
#     The specified issue numbers are left in their current status, but 
#     the contents of this commit message are added to their notes. 
#
# A fairly complicated example of what you can do is with a commit message
# of:
#
#    Changed blah and foo to do this or that. Fixes #10 and #12, and refs #12.
#
# This will close #10 and #12, and add a note to #12.

import re
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime 
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
depr = '(not used anymore)'
parser.add_option('-e', '--require-envelope', dest='envelope', default='',
                  help="""
Require commands to be enclosed in an envelope.
If -e[], then commands must be in the form of [closes #4].
Must be two characters.""")
parser.add_option('-p', '--project', dest='project',
                  help='Path to the Trac project.')
parser.add_option('-r', '--revision', dest='rev',
                  help='Repository revision number.')
parser.add_option('-u', '--user', dest='user',
                  help='The user who is responsible for this action '+depr)
parser.add_option('-m', '--msg', dest='msg',
                  help='The log message to search '+depr)
parser.add_option('-c', '--encoding', dest='encoding',
                  help='The encoding used by the log message '+depr)
parser.add_option('-s', '--siteurl', dest='url',
                  help=depr+' the base_url from trac.ini will always be used.')

(options, args) = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

if not 'PYTHON_EGG_CACHE' in os.environ:
    os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(options.project, '.egg-cache')

from trac.env import open_environment
from trac.ticket.notification import TicketNotifyEmail
from trac.ticket import Ticket
from trac.ticket.web_ui import TicketModule
# TODO: move grouped_changelog_entries to model.py
from trac.util.text import to_unicode
from trac.util.datefmt import utc
from trac.versioncontrol.api import NoSuchChangeset

ticket_prefix = '(?:#|(?:ticket|issue|bug)[: ]?)'
ticket_reference = ticket_prefix + '[0-9]+'
ticket_command =  (r'(?P<action>[A-Za-z]*).?'
                   '(?P<ticket>%s(?:(?:[, &]*|[ ]?and[ ]?)%s)*)' %
                   (ticket_reference, ticket_reference))

if options.envelope:
    ticket_command = r'\%s%s\%s' % (options.envelope[0], ticket_command,
                                    options.envelope[1])

command_re = re.compile(ticket_command)
ticket_re = re.compile(ticket_prefix + '([0-9]+)')

class CommitHook:
    _supported_cmds = {'close':      '_cmdClose',
                       'closed':     '_cmdClose',
                       'closes':     '_cmdClose',
                       'fix':        '_cmdClose',
                       'fixed':      '_cmdClose',
                       'fixes':      '_cmdClose',
                       'addresses':  '_cmdRefs',
                       're':         '_cmdRefs',
                       'references': '_cmdRefs',
                       'refs':       '_cmdRefs',
                       'see':        '_cmdRefs'}

    def __init__(self, project=options.project, author=options.user,
                 rev=options.rev, url=options.url):
        self.env = open_environment(project)
        repos = self.env.get_repository()
        repos.sync()

        # Instead of bothering with the encoding, we'll use unicode data
        # as provided by the Trac versioncontrol API (#1310).
        try:
            chgset = repos.get_changeset(rev)
        except NoSuchChangeset:
            return # out of scope changesets are not cached
        self.author = chgset.author
        self.rev = rev
        self.msg = "(In [%s]) %s" % (rev, chgset.message)
        self.now = datetime.now(utc)

        cmd_groups = command_re.findall(self.msg)

        tickets = {}
        for cmd, tkts in cmd_groups:
            funcname = CommitHook._supported_cmds.get(cmd.lower(), '')
            if funcname:
                for tkt_id in ticket_re.findall(tkts):
                    func = getattr(self, funcname)
                    tickets.setdefault(tkt_id, []).append(func)

        for tkt_id, cmds in tickets.iteritems():
            try:
                db = self.env.get_db_cnx()

                ticket = Ticket(self.env, int(tkt_id), db)
                for cmd in cmds:
                    cmd(ticket)

                # determine sequence number... 
                cnum = 0
                tm = TicketModule(self.env)
                for change in tm.grouped_changelog_entries(ticket, db):
                    if change['permanent']:
                        cnum += 1

                ticket.save_changes(self.author, self.msg, self.now, db, cnum+1)
                db.commit()

                tn = TicketNotifyEmail(self.env)
                tn.notify(ticket, newticket=0, modtime=self.now)
            except Exception, e:
                # import traceback
                # traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)
                print>>sys.stderr, 'Unexpected error while processing ticket ' \
                                   'ID %s: %s' % (tkt_id, e)


    def _cmdClose(self, ticket):
        ticket['status'] = 'closed'
        ticket['resolution'] = 'fixed'

    def _cmdRefs(self, ticket):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 5:
        print "For usage: %s --help" % (sys.argv[0])
        print
        print "Note that the deprecated options will be removed in Trac 0.12."
    else:
        CommitHook()
```

If anyone can see why the python script is failing in someway it would really help me out.
Thanks... 
.wm

--- update

Traced out the command and got the following in the log file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Repos\Project\hooks\trac-post-commit-resolve-ticket-ref.py", line 209, in <module>
    CommitHook()
  File "E:\Repos\Project\hooks\trac-post-commit-resolve-ticket-ref.py", line 144, in __init__
    repos = self.env.get_repository()
  File "c:\program files\bitnami trac stack\trac\lib\site-packages\Trac-0.11.6-py2.5.egg\trac\env.py", line 305, in get_repository
    return RepositoryManager(self).get_repository(authname)
  File "c:\program files\bitnami trac stack\trac\lib\site-packages\Trac-0.11.6-py2.5.egg\trac\versioncontrol\api.py", line 142, in get_repository
    error=to_unicode(connector.error)))
trac.core.TracError: Unsupported version control system "svn": "DLL load failed with error code 182"
```

As I had this working at some point before messing with SSL I'm wondering if something has been moved or deleted in error... any clues?

Comment: Are you able to run 'import svn' from within a python interactive session?

Answer (score 3):

Imports were working from command line. The problem turned out to be the path. It wasn't working setting the python path in the script file or as an system variable as PYTHON_PATH or PYTHONPATH. It would run the python command correctly like that but would then not use the correct svn bindings. Adding the python dir location to the system Path worked. thanks anyway!